# ESLint error about Unexpected String Concatenation

Tags: javascript, eslint, template-literals

I have the following:

```
return (useWordBoundary ? subString.substr(0, subString.lastIndexOf(' ')) : subString) + '\u2026';
```

`Eslint` is rejecting my code saying:

> Suggest using template literals instead of string concatenation.
>   (prefer-template)

What is wrong with the above?

Comment: What don't you understand? Do you know what a template literal is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It's a style question** really. In your example, there's arguably not a lot of benefit in using template literals:

```
return `${useWordBoundary ? subString.substr(0, subString.lastIndexOf(' ')) : subString}\u2026`;
```

---

**In other situations, it makes code more readable:**

```
return `Hello, ${name}!`;

// vs.

return 'Hello, ' + name + '!';
```

---

If you choose to, you can selectively **disable a rule for a specific line** via a comment:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line prefer-template
return (useWordBoundary ? subString.substr(0, subString.lastIndexOf(' ')) : subString) + '\u2026';
```

Answer (score 4):

Template literals are also known as String Interpolation.

**Your code must follow this syntax:**

```
return `${(useWordBoundary ? subString.substr(0, subString.lastIndexOf(' ')) : subString)} '\u2026'`;
```

See? isn't necessary to concatenate using `+` operator.

```js
var greeting = "Hello";

var completeGreeting = `${greeting} World!`;

console.log(completeGreeting);
```

See? the string is built using the parameters within this expression: `${}`

## Resource

- [Template literals (String Interpolation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [that rule's documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template) it simply flags any string concatenation with `+`. Instead, it suggests using ES6 template literals. Here's how you'd do that in your code:

```
return `${(useWordBoundary ? subString.substr(0, subString.lastIndexOf(' ')) : subString)}\u2026`;
```

You can read more about template literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different example using eslint **error: Unexpected string concatenation           | prefer-template**:

**(YES)**

```
const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
```

vs

**(NO)**

```
const value = '; ' + document.cookie;
const parts = value.split('; ' + name + '=');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found it useful for not only template related variables but also scripting variables as well, like:
I was getting this error for a concatenation as it was like this:

```
   if ($('#' + data.id_field).children().length === 0) {
  $(e.target).prepend($(e.target), ContactWrapper);
}
```

So I fixed it by using like this:

```
    if ($(`#${data.id_field}`).children().length === 0) {
  $(e.target).prepend($(e.target), ContactWrapper);
}
```

Hope this example helps!